# Regex last occurence of digit before some string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex to retrieve last number if there was a number or any number if there wasn't any from a string.
Examples:

```
 6 łyżek stopionego masła -> 6
5 łyżek blabla, 6 łyżek masła -> 6
5 łyżek mąki lub masła -> 5
```

I'm matching only on masła (changing variable) so it has to be included in regex

EDIT:
I cannot explain what I actually need:
Here is regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/pEeRk3/1

EDIT2:
Emma's solution works great, but I would need to parse decimals and 2multiple digit numbers as well, meaning that those would match as well:
https://regex101.com/r/pEeRk3/3 - I added examples with answers in the link

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the last occurence of a digit with a decimal and you word has to follow this value, you might use lookarounds:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)(?!.*\d)(?=.*masła)
```

- `(?<!\S)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)` Match 1+ digits with an optional past to match a dot and 1+ digits
- `(?!.*\d)` assert that there are no more digits following
- `(?=.*masła)` Assert what is on the right is your word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEeRk3/4)

Or you might use a capturing group:

```
(?<!\S)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[^\d\n]* masła(?!\S)[^\d\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEeRk3/5)

Answer (score 1):

This expression might simply suffice:

```
.*([0-9])
```

if we are interested in one digit only, or

```
.*([0-9]+)
```

if multiple digits might be desired.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/pwhLRL/1)

If those strings with `masła` are desired, we can expand our expression to:

```
(?=.*masła).*([0-9])
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/COBXFD/1/)

If we would not be validating our numbers and our number would be valid, with commas or dots, then this expression might likely return our desired output:

```
(?=.*masła)([0-9,.]+)(\D*)$
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/7scROQ/1/)

Comment: Sry, I have miswritten my needs. Edited post for clarification

Comment: @ohwelppp this is likely what you need, but what Emma didn't mention is that the number is to be extracted from the first capturing group. See this slightly modified demo where I match the whole line to replace it by the last number it contains : https://regex101.com/r/pEeRk3/2

Comment: great, I didn't know about positive lookahead - seems like very useful technique,thx!

Comment: actually, I think that I forgot about the case that I need the number not the digit. I'll add another edit if you can take a look

Comment: nah, numbeers are prevalidated. Thx a lot, thats perfect!